# Android Kotlin Coroutines - Call Api Every X Seconds on Background

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I've build clean architectured app (with mvvm, use cases, compose). I've a `CoinListViewModel` for list all crypto coins by using [CoinPaprika API](https://coinpaprika.com/en/api/). It is like;

```
@HiltViewModel
class CoinListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getCoinsUseCase: GetCoinsUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(CoinListState())
    val state: State<CoinListState> = _state

    init {
        getCoins()
    }

    private fun getCoins() {
        getCoinsUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = CoinListState(coins = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state.value = CoinListState(
                        error = result.message ?: "An unexpected error occured"
                    )
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = CoinListState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

And this viewmodel is used in my `CoinListScreen` like;

```
@Composable
fun CoinListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CoinListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(state.coins) { coin ->
                CoinListItem(
                    coin = coin,
                    onItemClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.CoinDetailScreen.route + "/${coin.id}")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        if(state.error.isNotBlank()) {
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
        if(state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

And that is my `GetCoinsUseCase`:

```
class GetCoinsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CoinRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<Coin>>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading<List<Coin>>())
            val coins = repository.getCoins().map { it.toCoin() }
            emit(Resource.Success<List<Coin>>(coins))

        } catch(e: HttpException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occured"))
        } catch(e: IOException){
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>("Couldn't reach to server. Check your internet connection."))
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions;

1. How can I make this API call every 3 seconds ?
2. How can I continue to do API call on background in phone ?

Comment: If by "on background" you mean when your app is not currently on screen, then you cannot do this with coroutines. You would need WorkManager or a foreground Service. If you mean while on screen, you can simply put your code in a while(true) loop with a `delay(3000)` call in a launched coroutine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah I mean like that. hmm, sad... What about my first question ?

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm so sorry but where should I wrap with while loop ? I'm little newbie for coroutines. Can I kindly request you to write as answer ?

Comment: I’m very familiar with coroutines, but not familiar enough with Compose yet to confidently write a correct answer about how to launch your coroutine from the appropriate CoroutineScope.

Comment: 1. You can use a `delay`, 2. You cannot do that unless you use a solution like WorkManager (minimum 15 minutes interval, not exact) or Foreground Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a loop with a delay in your use case:

```
class GetCoinsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CoinRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<Coin>>> = flow {
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
            try {
                emit(Resource.Loading<List<Coin>>())
                val coins = repository.getCoins().map { it.toCoin() }
                emit(Resource.Success<List<Coin>>(coins))

            } catch(e: HttpException) {
                emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occured"))
            } catch(e: IOException){
               emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>("Couldn't reach to server. Check your internet connection."))
            }

            // Wait until next request
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
}
```

You could also move the loop and delay call around depending on the precise functionality you are looking for. For example, to stop once there is an error you could do

```
class GetCoinsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CoinRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<Coin>>> = flow {
        emit(Resource.Loading<List<Coin>>())
        try {
            while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
                val coins = repository.getCoins().map { it.toCoin() }
                emit(Resource.Success<List<Coin>>(coins))

                // Wait until next request
                delay(3000)
            }
        } catch(e: HttpException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occured"))
        } catch(e: IOException){
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>("Couldn't reach to server. Check your internet connection."))
        }
    }
}
```

This should already naturally "run in the background" as long as your app is running and you are not cancelling the coroutine manually when going in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The way to repeat a task in Jetpack Compose is

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while(true) {
        vm.someMethod()
        delay(3000)
    }
}
```

The someMethod is the method that fetches the coin data.